# How to handle interface from graphql schema in java pojo

Tags: interface, graphql-java

I have to create pojos from graphql schema file into java. like for
type Student{
name:String
age:Int
}
i created pojo

```
class Student{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // setter and getters
}
```

how to handle interface  in java classes like

```
interface prop{
    alttext: String
    description: String
    linkurl: String
    title: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a work around for my question, might be best solution is some thing else-
i created abstract class in java from interface of graphql schema. like below -

```
public abstract class prop {
private String alttext;
private String description;
private String linkurl;
private String title;
}
```

and for class extending this abstract class use super in constructor in child class to initialized abstract class members.

Comment: Did it work? I could not make it work